# How do I describe a hierarchical relationship between software objects?

Tags: software

I'm trying to express a particular relationship between two software resources. The relationship is such that one of the resources is the "main" or "original" one and is required before the system can create the other resource. For example, the *invoice* resource is derived from the *customer* resource, the "main" resource. What shall I call the relationship, in either direction? I could think of the following alternatives:

- Main resource and derived resource
- Origin resource and derived resource
- Super-resource and sub-resource
- Supra-resource and infra-resource
- Parent resource and child resource (I can't use this one because it's reserved for another form of relationship between objects.)

Comment: It's not really a question of one being main and one being subsidiary; it's a relative relationship of one being prior and the other dependent on it. It's better to label the relationship, not the entities, else how do you cope when your subsidiary resource has something else that depends on it in turn?

Comment: Use a metaphor with a tree built in. Say that a subroutine _inherits_ its constants or properties or whatever from something higher.

Comment: Primary, secondary.

Comment: I hadn't clarified that I wanted a name for the relationship, in either direction, not the name for the objects themselves. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Not an uncommon problem. One must have words to refer to elements of an outline that are I, II and III.

You would want to say **Original resource** rather than Origin resource. Then **Derived** resources after that would be fine. This is best as it gives you the top, first, primo object that must be seen before any others can be referenced.

You could use **Primary** as the first and **Secondary** for the second and **Tertiary** for the one driving from the Secondary. Though that may get clumsy for some to use.

Using Supra and sub would mean you're using sub-sub to increasing depths.